# Discord.js - Bot messages LIMIT?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a bot with which you have to verify yourself to be on our Discord server
(The verification takes place in the DM`s)

Recently we have the problem that certain members of our Discord cannot write to the bot.

Everyone allowed everyone to send a message to the person

[image]

Each of the people is on our Discord Server, allows the person to write messages and have not blocked the bot

**The bot does not issue any error messages**

**We would be delighted to find a quick solution**

Comment: Hi, please don't tag this as node.js, discord.js, javascript or discord.net, this has nothing to do with coding.

Comment: It does have to do with discord.js assuming he's using that library, prob not discord.net, but the others are fine, although he should add some code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided any code snippets, logs or error messages, it's a bit difficult to assess your situation... but here are some basic troubleshooting steps that you could follow:

- Remove and re-authenticate the bot into the server.
- Double check that you have enabled DM's.
- Check the console for any errors that could pertain to direct messaging  issues with users in the server. (especially from successful DM's)
- Try to notice any differences between the users in the server who are
  able to message the bot, versus those who cannot.
- Ensure the bot isn't running more than one instance. (i.e. you might
  have more than one bot running on the same token!)

I highly recommend giving more detail, because usually a question pertaining to broken/lost functionality would usually attach code or error logs to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will repeat the authentication with the server.

I did not give any error messages because there are none.

As I said, only certain members can write to the bot

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that you either didn't enable DMs or the bot is not in the server.

Otherwise, this problem will not occur.